# Properties of basic set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question is about a set:
$$B=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n\} \subset \mathbb R$$
And would like to know how to calculate $B^n$ where $n \in\Bbb N$?

Comment: $B^n$ is the set of all n-tuples of elements of $B$. Did you mean that all elements of $B$ are in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sorry I've already corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $B = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n\} \subset \mathbb R$, with $|B| = n$,

$B^n$ is the set of all ordered n-tuples of elements of $B$:

The exponent refers to the operation of the Cartesian Product of $B$ with itself, n times:
$$B^n = \underbrace{B \times B \times \cdots \times B}_{\Large\text{n times}} =\{(b_1, b_2,\cdots, b_n) \mid b_i \in B\}.$$

Can you figure out how to calculate: $|B^n|$? There are $n$ choices for position 1, $n$ choices for position 2, ..., $n$ choices for position $n$:

$$|B^n| = \underbrace{n\times n\times \cdots \times n}_{\Large \text{n times}} = n^n$$

Comment: You may want to use `\cdots` $\cdots$ instead of `\ldots` $\ldots$, when you are using them between symbols, like $\times$, $+$, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @user17762 I'm surprised I used `\ldots`: I virtually always use `\cdots`, even when listing elements in a set, with no operations involved! Kind of "autopilot" for me. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @user17762: A neat [trick](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77737/dots-versus-ldots-is-there-a-difference) is to always use `\dots` (which also works with MathJax): `$a_1, \dots, a_n$ and $a_1 \times \dots \times a_n$` produces "$a_1, \dots, a_n$ and $a_1 \times \dots \times a_n$"

Comment: @TMM Thanks. I wasn't aware that `\dots` adapts accordingly. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

For a set $S$, we often write $S^n$ to denote the $n$-fold cartesian product of $S$ with itself. In your case, we would have
$$
B^n = \{(b_1, b_2,\ldots, b_n)\mid b_i = a_{i_k}, a_{i_k}\in B\}.
$$
In other words, $B^n$ consists of ordered $n$-tuples, where each element in the tuple is an element of the original $B$.

Answer (score 0):

For the simpler version of what $B^n$ looks like, set up the Cartesian product of $B$'s.

$$\underbrace{B \times B \times \cdots \times B}_{\text{n times}}$$

Then, we have n-tuples consisting on elements from $B$.  As what Stahl just showed to you, we have:

$$B^n = \{(b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n) | \text{for each } b_j \in B \text{ for j} = \{1,2,3,\dots, n\} \}$$